# Is there a way for VB6 to throw a type mismatch error when assigning a variable of the same type?

Tags: vb6, type-mismatch

I am trying to figure out the cause of a type mismatch error, but I don't understand the reason it is even being thrown. I am assigning to a variable of the same type that is being assigned from.

```
Begin bxControls.starTable m_tblClaims 'Defined at the top of the form file

Dim objTable As PVDataTable5.DataTable
Set objTable = m_tblClaims.Table
```

```
Begin PVDataTable5.DataTable dtTable 'Defined at the top of the .ctl file

'Property inside of bxControls.starTable
Public Property Get Table() As Object
Attribute Table.VB_MemberFlags = "40"
        Set Table = dtTable
End Property
```

As you can see, the assignment taking place should not be having a type mismatch since they are the same type. Any help would be awesome. TIA

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: The error is thrown on "Set objTable = m_tblClaims.Table"

Comment: Is `m_tblClaims.Table` of type `PVDataTable5.DataTable`?

Comment: Yes, in the second snippet, I provided the property getter for the `m_tblClaims.Table` `dtTable` is defined at the top of that snippet as well.

Comment: Since the Table property is of type Object, I think its pretty likely you don't have the right kind of object in there. Why is it defined as Object, that's often a bad sign.

Comment: I inherited the codebase, so I am not sure why the decision was made to have the Table property as type object.

Comment: Is `dtTable` some kind of user-control which is referenced from a compiled OCX?

Comment: I believe that it is within a user control being referenced from an OCX

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Dim objTable As PVDataTable5.DataTable
Set objTable = m_tblClaims.Table.Object
```

Note that this might work in IDE but fail when compiled.

The story of user-controls is mostly of complete lies from the IDE. For instance all user-control properties/methods are called late-bound, even if the IDE intellisense gives look like the callsite is early-bound.

For each user-control type that is currently loaded in the IDE (as part of a project group for instance) the IDE creates surrogate date-type with merged original control properties/methods and some VB supplied ones (like `Visible` etc.) which are coming from `VBControlExtender` class.

That is why `Dim objTable As PVDataTable5.DataTable` sometimes is not declaration of `PVDataTable5.DataTable` data-type but of the surrogate `PVDataTable5.DataTable` from an OCA file, that is when the user-control is loaded in the IDE.

The only sane way to pass references to VB6 user-controls that works both if the user-control is loaded and when referenced in compiled OCX is to pass `VBControlExtender` instead and use its `Object` property to access the wrapped reference.

Comment: @DylanMangold So it must be the other way around -- your `Property Get Table() As Object` is returning real control reference while your `Dim objTable As PVDataTable5.DataTable` expects a `VBControlExtender` and bombs. Try changing `Property Get Table` to explicit `VBControlExtender` type from `Object`.